# PostGIS - raster coodinates - no result for negative values of GPS

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have data in raster and try to run this query

```
WITH ref As ( SELECT (ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(-20.12, 51.50), 4326)) AS pt ) 
SELECT ST_Value(raw_data, 1, ref.pt) AS val_0
FROM model_data
```

The problem is, that for negative longitude (-20.12) I do not get any output (latitude can be +- 51.50 and I still getting results).

My data `st_upperleftx = -0.125` and `st_upperlefty = 90.125`. I can add offsets to coordinates lat/lon manually, but that is not what I want, because every raster can have a different upperleft corner. I thought, that postgis should take care of this automatically, but I am obviously missing something somewhere.

Comment: ST_Point(-20.12, 51.50), 4326) is inside your raster bounds? try to set exclude_nodata_value to false ST_Value(raster rast, integer band, geometry pt, boolean exclude_nodata_value=true);

Comment: Taking upper left in consideration, it is outside the bounds... however, it is still some place on earth, and my data contains the whole world.

Comment: Are you sure? Test with other positive values outside the bounds like longitude 0 latitude 91 and test if return values (I think should not return and that would prove that is because there is no data since you're out of the bounds and this has nothing to do with negative longitude values). Or use exclude_nodata_values flag set to false. I am wrong?

Comment: You are correct. If I am outside bounds, it will return no value. However, that is not my problem. My problem is, that I want to convert real-world lat/lon into the bounds. In GPS, I can have -20. I can do nothing with data, that are "shifted", so the negatove values are out-of-bounds (check my info about upperleftx/y).

Comment: You're upper left x is -0.125, so yeah, that point's out of bounds. Does your world data actually have longitude extent of 0 to +360? If so, you'll have to +360 any negative longitude/x values.